# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<map<String,Object>>' in type cast

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, android-studio, dart

This error keeps appearing and change from "not a subtype of type String" to what says on the screen

[Error on Flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDfHw.png)

this is the quiz.dart

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './pregunta.dart';
import './respuesta.dart';
import './cuestionario.dart';
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget{
  final List<Map<String,Object>> preguntas;
  final int preguntasIndex;
  final Function? responderPregunta;

  Quiz({
   required this.preguntas,
   required this.preguntasIndex,
   required this.responderPregunta,

});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [

        Pregunta(
          preguntas[preguntasIndex]['textoPregunta'] ,
        ),
        ...(preguntas![preguntasIndex!]['respuestas'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((respuesta) {
          return Respuesta(() => responderPregunta!(respuesta['puntuacion']), respuesta['texto']);})
            .toList(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

//if here preguntas[preguntasIndex]['textoPregunta'] there is a "as String" the error in the title appears, if not the red underline appears with The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:y_esa_senal/resultado.dart';
import './quiz.dart';
class Cuestionario extends StatefulWidget{
  const Cuestionario({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return CuestionarioState();
  }
}
class CuestionarioState extends State<Cuestionario>{
  final _preguntas = [
    {
      'textoPreguntas': '1. Que Significa esta Señal?',
      'respuestas:': [
        {'texto': 'Detenerse', 'puntuacion': 1},
        {'texto': 'Continuar', 'puntuacion': -1},
        {'texto': 'Acelerar', 'puntuacion': -1},
        {'texto': 'Mirar a ambos lados', 'puntuacion': -1},
      ]
    },
    {
      'textoPreguntas': '1. Que Significa esta Señal?',
      'respuestas:': [
        {'texto': 'Detenerse', 'puntuacion': 1},
        {'texto': 'Continuar', 'puntuacion': -1},
        {'texto': 'Acelerar', 'puntuacion': -1},
        {'texto': 'Mirar a ambos lados', 'puntuacion': -1},
      ]
    },
    {
      'textoPreguntas': '1. Que Significa esta Señal?',
      'respuestas:': [
        {'texto': 'Detenerse', 'puntuacion': 1},
        {'texto': 'Continuar', 'puntuacion': -1},
        {'texto': 'Acelerar', 'puntuacion': -1},
        {'texto': 'Mirar a ambos lados', 'puntuacion': -1},
      ]
    },

  ];
  var _preguntasIndex=0;
  var _puntuacionTotal=0;
  void _reiniciarQuiz(){
    setState((){
      _preguntasIndex=0;
      _puntuacionTotal=0;
    });
  }
void _responderPregunta(int puntuacion){
    _puntuacionTotal+=puntuacion;
    setState((){
      _preguntasIndex=_preguntasIndex+1;
    });
    print(_preguntasIndex);
    if(_preguntasIndex<_preguntas.length){
      print('hay mas preguntas');
    } else{
      print('No hay mas preguntas');
    }
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Geeks for Geeks'),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF00E676),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: _preguntasIndex < _preguntas.length
              ? Quiz(
            responderPregunta: _responderPregunta,
            preguntasIndex: _preguntasIndex,
            preguntas: _preguntas,
          ) //Quiz
              : Resultado(_puntuacionTotal, _reiniciarQuiz),
        ), //Padding
      ), //Scaffold
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ); //MaterialApp
  }
}
```

this is the pregunta.dart

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './resultado.dart';
import './quiz.dart';

class Pregunta extends StatelessWidget{
  final String textoPregunta;
  Pregunta(this.textoPregunta);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Text(
    textoPregunta!,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center
  ),

);
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typos in your `Cuestionario` widget in the `_preguntas` variable.

Check both `textoPreguntas` and `respuestas:` .(extra "s" and extra ":")

Comment: thanks. I already fixed the typos but the problem remains. Also checked all the possible null variables (That's supposed to be the problem ) but cant be able to fix.

Comment: I ran you code and it's working fine. Did you try changing ```List<Map<String,Object>>``` to ```List<Map<String,dynamic>>```?